# iOS4 SDK + Three20 Build issue

Tags: iphone, three20, ios4, xcodebuild

I installed the latest iOS4 SDK which replaced my existing SDKs (so I no longer have anything other than 3.2, 4.0).

I also checked out the latest Three20 from github, and now whenever I'm about to Build a new Three20 app, or even run the samples I get the following error:

```
Build Three20Core of project Three20Core with configuration Debug

Check dependencies

[BEROR]error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphonesimulator3.0'
```

Is Three20 not yet iOS4 SDK compatible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the "Base SDK" in the downloaded project info settings from 3.0 to 3.2 or 4.0

Comment: Well, It wouldn't work for me, because after selecting the "Base SDK" to 3.2, I forgot to change to Simulator in the overview dropdown. It works now!

Comment: You in fact need to change the base SDK in each of the three20 components.

Comment: I still cannot find it. I went to "Edit Project Settings" and changed Base SDK to 4.2 (the one if have) and still get the error that Simulator 3.0 cannot be found.

Comment: I figured it out: you have to "Get info" on the target and then change the SDK there, too.